# Proving that these two sets are denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

(a) $S_k=\{A\subset\mathbb{N}: |A|=k\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

(b) $S = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$

Work: For (a), I am not too sure about what approach I should use. I think finding a bijective function between the $S_k$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is hard to do . I also thought about using the Schroeder-Bernstein theorem and find injective functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S_k$and $g:S_k\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ in order to prove that $S_k$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are numerically equivalent. However, I have a hard time finding and proving these injective functions.
I haven't really looked at (b) as I have yet to complete (a).

Comment: What properties are you allowed to use? Are you allowed to use the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable? What about a countable union of finite sets?

Comment: I think it's actually easier to just find a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $S$, rather than each $S_k$ individually.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Also, @AlexZorn, yes we are allowed to use that theorem.

Comment: One could try a proof with induction over $k$ using a [Cantoresque diagonal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to write S_k as a countable union of finite sets. And if you can use the theorem, (b) follows directly from (a).

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be clear that $\mathbb N$ has cardinality less than or equal to that of $S_k$ and $S$; the hard part is showing the reverse direction, that is, finding injective maps $\mathbb N\hookrightarrow S_k$ and $\mathbb N\hookrightarrow S$. One way to make such maps is by using prime factorization. Specifically, let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime number. I assume that $\mathbb N$ starts at $1$, not $0$. Then the map
$\varphi_k:S_k\to\mathbb N$ given by
$$
\varphi_k(\{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k\})=p_1^{n_1}\cdot p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_k^{n_k}
$$
is an injection owing to the uniqueness of prime factorization.
More generally, the map $\varphi:S\to \mathbb N$ given by 
$$
\varphi(A)=\varphi_k(A)\text{ when $A\subset\mathbb N$ has $k$ elements }
$$
is an injection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I still don't understand how to find injective maps from N to $S_k$. Perhaps, instead it may be easier to prove that the function from $S_k$ to $N$ is surjective?

Comment: I sort of took it for granted, didn't I? Sorry about that. As a warmup, how could you get an injective math from $\mathbb N$ to $S_1$? What about $\mathbb N$ to $S_2$?

Comment: Is it possible for $\mathbb{N}$ to have an injective function to $S_1$ since $S_1$ only has 1 element? Sorry if I am slow, I just began this subject in class and I still need to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I was confused for a second. Would $f(n)=n$ work?

Comment: Almost. Technically the map would be $f(n)=\{n\}$. Now what about $S_2$?

Comment: $f(n)=\{\{n,n+1\}\}$. Would that be an injection? Since $A$ would have two elements.

Comment: Right! (Except you want $f(n)=\{n,n+1\}$.) Now what do you do for $S_3$? What about the general case?

Comment: Then simply you would have $n$ to $n+k$. Awesome, thanks!